# Dart: How to loop over DOM elements

Tags: html, dart

I need to iterate over check boxes in my HTML in order that I may detect the checked/not-checked state but have not been able to find an example of how to do that. I'd like it to be fast and it occurred to me that storing the element references in an indexed list might serve but I would build the list programmatically.

I'm a novice at HTML, CSS, and Dart.

My HTML:

```
<div id="check-boxes">
  <input id="B12" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    <label for="B12">B12&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
  <input id="B10" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    <label for="B10">B10&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
  <input id="B8" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    <label for="B8">B8&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
  <input id="BBW" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    <label for="BBW">Wide&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
  <input id="freeze" type="checkbox">
    <label id="lblFreeze" for="freeze">Freeze</label>
 </div>
```

(Actually I do not want to include last check box id=freeze.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use :

```dart
// retrieve checkboxes with a CSS selector
final checkBoxes = querySelectorAll('#check-boxes input[type=checkbox]');

// iterate over the checkboxes
checkBoxes.forEach((checkbox) {
  // do something
});

// iterate over the checked checkboxes
checkBoxes.where((e) => e.checked).forEach((checkbox) {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: or if you want to iterate only over checked ones, use `querySelector('#check-boxes input[checked]');`

Comment: nice solution i didn't see it before i post mine

Comment: Shouldn't that be "querySelectorAll"

Comment: Right, answer is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @SamyMassoud I notice that if I the Dart editor doesn't know the what 'checkbox' is in the foreach code.  Is that because it is determined at run time? For instance, if I use SamyMassoud's solution the editor suggests methods, attributes, etc.

Comment: You don't get assist because `querySelectorAll` returns a generic `ElementList` (basically a List of Element). If you use `ElementList<CheckboxInputElement> checkBoxes` instead of `final checkBoxes` you should get content assist everywhere.

Comment: also you still can use this answer but to get suggested methods you have to cast checkbox to CheckboxInputElement
{CheckboxInputElement el = checkbox;} inside foreach

Answer (score 2):

i would do it this way

```
import 'dart:html';

void main (){

  //Get all checkboxes in a list
  var all_checkboxes = querySelectorAll('#check-boxes input[type="checkbox"]');
  //Loop through your list
  all_checkboxes.forEach((CheckboxInputElement el){
      //do any logic you want here
       if (el.checked == true){}
  });
}
```